# Point to using vSyncCount higher than 1?

Tags: unity, vsync

Is there a point to using [QualitySettings.vSyncCount](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-vSyncCount.html) higher than 1?

From my understanding it sets the framerate to fractions of the screen refreshrate (i.e: FPS = refreshrate/vSyncCount). So 1 is standard VSync and 2 to 4 make no difference compared to 1 for eliminating tearing and only artificially limit framerate.

The only use for this that I can think of is for reducing power-draw for battery-driven devices like phones. Am I missing something?